# sample variance

Tags: r, variance

```
function(x) var(sum(((x - mean(x))^2)/(n - 1)))
```

This is my function but it does not seem to work.
Are we allowed to use the var in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is significantly harder than you think it is; you can't compute it directly the way you're trying to do it. (Hint: when you take the `sum()` you get a single value/vector of length 1, so the sample variance of that vector is `NA`.)  [This post on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance) derives the variance of the sample variance as `mu_4/n - sigma^4*(n-3)/(n*(n-1))`, where `mu_4` is the *fourth central moment*; you could also see [this post on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/reference-for-mathrmvars2-sigma4-left-frac2n-1-frac-kappan) or [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance) (different derivations present the result in terms of the fourth central moment, the kurtosis, or the excess kurtosis ...)  So:

```r
set.seed(101)
r <- rnorm(100)
mu_4 <- mean((r-mean(r))^4)
sigma_4 <- var(r)^2
n <- length(r)
mu_4/n - sigma_4*(n-3)/(n*(n-1))  ## 0.01122
```

Be careful:

```r
var(replicate(100000,var(rnorm(100))))
```

gives about 0.0202. At least it's not the wrong order of magnitude, but it's a factor of 2 different from the example above. My guess is just that the estimate is itself highly variable (which wouldn't be surprising since it depends on the fourth moment ...) (I tried the estimation method above a few times and it does indeed seem highly variable ...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will have to figure it more about this :)